Is there a way to dismiss my PC's lockscreen when connecting via Steam Remote Play?
My PC is running Windows 10 and only has one local account with NO password. However, when it's on the lock screen and I try to start a Remote Play session from my laptop on the same network, it won't connect until the lock screen is dismissed which consists of simply clicking the login button since it doesn't have a password.
My question is, how do I set this up so it gets automatically dismissed without needing to set up a remote control app like TeamViewer?

There is no way (I know) to enable steam to disable the lockscreen.
Edit
A comment clarified that the question resolves around the time based lockscreen.

Open Settings / System / Power & Sleep
Set both settings to an appropiate time or never.


Just disable the automatic lockscreen through your account settings.

Go to Start Menu / Settings / Accounts / Sign-in Options.
On this screen, Look for "Require sign-in" and set it to "Never".

From Microsoft Learn 
You can also configure autologin for your user with steam in autostart. Then you can also use Wake on LAN.
There are multiple ways to configure autologin.
The easiest way is to use the autologon.exe Tool from the Sysinterals-Collection. Just download it, start it, enter your credentials and restart.
Some versions of windows require that there is a password configured for your user.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/autologon

I don't need Autologin from Sysinternals because like I said, my account does not have a password. Moreover, it automatically logs in after a fresh boot up, the problem is, after the computer is left for a while, it sometimes goes to the lock screen. And lastly, there is no such option in the Settings app app for requiring login.
